# Issues linking data in Flask / MongoDB

Tags: python, html, mongodb, flask, jinja2

New to the whole coding thing, currently doing a course in Python/Flask and giving it my best shot.

I have a MongoDB Atlas DB, with 2 collections in it for drinks.

The structure looks like the below. The values in the array are the _id values of the ingredients in another collection.

```
_id:5e0f54d31c9d44000015483f
drinkName:"Margarita"
Ingredients:["5e13274e1c9d440000490ed8","5e1327571c9d440000490ed9","5e1327621c9d440000490eda","5e13276b1c9d440000490edb"]
```

And another collection with the below

```
_id:5e1327261c9d440000490ed7
ingredientName:"Slice Lemon"
```

My problem is I'm trying to render the results of the array in Flask on a page. But I can't seem to look up the object id's in the ingredients table, and display the ingredientName of the object.

I can display the array fine, but can't then go to the ingredients collection to get the name.

This is what I have in the html

```
           {% for ingredient in drink.ingredientList %}
            {% for ing in ingredients %}
            {% if ing._id == ingredient %}
            <li>
                {{ ing.ingredientName }}
            </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, because I feel like I'm banging my head against the wall at this point.

Comment: I think this is harder than it should because you're trying to force a relational model into MongoDB. Maybe you should update your question to include an explanation of the goal of the app, so a different schema can be designed.

Comment: dude. what library for mongo are you using? show us the code for getting the results from database. there is nothing wrong with your db, the problem is how you search for items.